# SVG Line chart on known axes

Tags: charts, svg, linechart

I want to create dynamically line chart (svg format). 
[image: Like this]

But svg coordinate system works inverse. Like this:

[image: SVG Coordinate]

When I have points like (0,9),(1,3),(2,6), graph will be drawing top to bottom.
But svg has [rotate](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) function. But when it turned to left (- direction) last value will be first point.

I need to draw line chart like mirroring it. But there is mirror function like roate or scale function :(

Is there any way to draw line chart on simple x y coordinates like :

[image: Known x y axis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirroring is scaling by a negative amount. If you scale the y-axis by -1 you should get what you want.